# Right click in JavaFX for Minesweeper

Tags: java, javafx

I want to open tiles with the left mouseclick and mark them with the right mouseclick. I read and tried a lot but somehow can't get this working.

```
private class Tile extends StackPane {
    private int x, y;
    private boolean hasBomb;
    private boolean isOpen = false;

    private Rectangle border = new Rectangle(TILE_SIZE - 2, TILE_SIZE - 2);
    private Text text = new Text();

    public Tile(int x, int y, boolean hasBomb) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.hasBomb = hasBomb;

        border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        border.setFill(Color.GREY);
        text.setFont(Font.font(18));
        text.setText(hasBomb ? "X" : "");
        text.setVisible(false);

        getChildren().addAll(border, text);

        setTranslateX(x * TILE_SIZE);
        setTranslateY(y * TILE_SIZE);

        onMouseClicked: function(e:MouseEvent):Void {
            if (e.button == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                setOnMouseClicked(e -> open());
            }
        }
    }
```

Could anyonw please help?

Comment: Define "not working."  What you have there looks like a syntax error.  It sure isn't Java.

Comment: Sorry, yes there are several syntax errors. I used this as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515547/right-click-in-javafx

Comment: @KendelVentonda: That's JavaFX **script**, Which is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went wrong with your `onMouseClicked` handler.

For the correct syntax of lambda expressions, see [the *Syntax* section of the oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax).

The correct way to do it would be

```
this.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        open();
    }
});
```

Furthermore there are some declarations missing in your code snippet:

- the `open` method
- the `TILE_SIZE` field

Comment: The both are declared later, didn't put it in here. But your solution is easy and very logical! Thank you a lot!